# .htaccess return 500 error fot rewritten URL

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I try to rewrite this URL

**http://domain.com/page?LINK=member-name**

to be

**http://domain.com/page/member-name**

The rule I've tried is:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^page/([^/]*)$ /page?LINK=$1 [L]
```

I call the request like this:

```
<a href="page/john-smith">John Smith</a>
```

Comment: I tried your solution. Still get the 500 error.

Comment: Check your Apache error.log to know reason of 500 error

Answer (score 0):

Try this, i am assuming page has .php extension.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^page/([^/]*)$ page.php?LINK=$1 [L]
```

Comment: Yes. It is .php. Looks like your solution is corect but I still get the 500 error :(